# How to organize country-specific classes in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm working on an application targeted to be used in multiple countries. However, since each country has its own peculiarity in the bookkeeping and financial domain, separate classes for similar tasks need to be written. The classes will probably share a common interface and that fact makes the problem slightly simpler.

It is not feasible nor is it maintainable to pack everything into one big class, hence a locale-like organization is needed, i.e. classes need to be loaded based on user's locale or their country setting.

Which are the best practices that can be implemented for this scenario?
Any Rails functionality already present that can be leveraged?

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't need DB access in these country-specific classes. They will do a call to an external web service (different for each country) and the main app code will store the response into a common DB field.

Comment: Why don't you use common class with fields which describe specifications?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: i mean to have a few classes describes all your needs. For example, when a user from Fr call your service /payment_methods/ then its would be dispatch to PaymentMethodsController where you check in requests object country by ip address and then depend on that it will call FrancePayments.methods. So you need to implement all base and related child classes. Also, for exceptional cases, e.g. country not found errors return BasePayments.methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've decided to use a simple const lookup approach:

```
some_class = const_get("ClassModule::#{language_code}::SomeClass")
if some_class.present?
    ...
```

It seems to do the trick. :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to use Single Table Inheritance or STI (for your models). This will definitely get you on the right track I think.

You could for instance have a generic `Finance` model and then have `Finance::France`, `Finance::UnitedKingdom` etc. Both of these namespaced models would inherit from `Finance`. You would then need to add a `type` (string) column on your DB. You can read more about STI at

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance

Comment: I actually don't need DB access in these country-specific classes. They will do a call to an external web service (different for each country) and store the response in a common DB field.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a little bit of your code and then we could think of ways to refactor/organize?

Comment: Sure: so, upon every transaction, each transaction also needs to be submitted to the corresponding government authority (for legal/fiscal reasons). Each country has its own authority (which works differently) and some countries do not require the submission to be done in the first place. Therefore, we need to build a custom solution that will do the submission whenever necessary and to the appropriate authority. Hope this helps...